# Exception trying to create a new Weblogic Domain

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have installed Oracle WebLogic Server 12.1.2.0 per the instructions.  When I run the `./configure.sh` it asks if I want to create a domain, I said no.  Further down the instructions it asks if I want to create a new domain and start WLS.  The following commands are listed:

```
$ mkdir /home/myhome/mydomain
$ cd /home/myhome/mydomain
$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $JAVA_OPTIONS -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    weblogic.Server
```

when the command is executed the following exception is generated:

```
[tester@kohls-enterprise-dev gravityDomain]$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java
$JAVA_OPTIONS -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m weblogic.Server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
weblogic/Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.Server
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    Could not find the main class: weblogic.Server. Program will exit.
```

I have ensured that the `MW_HOME` is set per the instructions and have run the `setWLSEnv.sh`

Any suggestions?

Thank you in Advanced
O. Frank

Comment: I have noticed that the $JAVA_OPTIONS in not getting set, There is nothing in the instructions about setting this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have weblogic.jar and many other jar files in the CLASSPATH. This is not the way to run a WebLogic Domain. You should create the domain and do it the prescribed way. If you really want to get low-key, include the following in your CLASSPATH

```
ant-all.jar
ant-contrib.jar
config-launch.jar
derbyclient.jar
derbynet.jar
tools.jar
weblogic.jar
weblogic_patch.jar
weblogic.server.modules_10.3.6.0.jar
weblogic_sp.jar
webservices.jar
xqrl.jar
```

Plus you would need a config.xml and additional files. Best would be to create a domain and scale down from there if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run configuration wizard: (config.sh)

a domain contains several files/directories, not only a few jar files.
the wizard will help you creating the domain (and the servers as well).

follow the steps from Oracle's documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLDCW/newdom.htm#WLDCW109